# "syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"

Tags: sql, insert

I got a syntax error in INSERT INTO statement, what might be the cause?

```vb
 Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
 conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Bro_Proj.accdb"
 Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Order(`Stud_ID`, `BookName`, `Quantity`, `sale`, `DateOfOrder`, `TimeOfOrder`)  VALUES (' " & TextBox1.Text & " ' , ' " & ComboBox3.Text & " ', " & NumericUpDown1.Value & ", ' " & TextBox10.Text & " ', # " & TextBox8.Text & " #, # " & TextBox9.Text & " #);"
 conn.Open()
 Dim sqlc As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
 sqlc.ExecuteNonQuery()
 conn.Close()
```

Comment: i think you need to wrap all your insert values in quotes; the last two fields have '#' outside the quotes, that's probably the cause of the error.

Comment: I don't see a question...

Comment: when i use this codes the error vb tells me is the title "syntax error in INSERT INTO"

Comment: here are the data types of my access file

Comment: Stud_ID     short text
BookName    short text
Quantity    short text
sale        short text
DateOfOrder short text
TimeOfOrder short text

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of the space characters existence when you are enclosing your date values.
Try to omit it:

```vb
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Order(`Stud_ID`, `BookName`, `Quantity`, `sale`, `DateOfOrder`, `TimeOfOrder`)
VALUES (' " & TextBox1.Text & " ' ,
    ' " & ComboBox3.Text & " ',
    " & NumericUpDown1.Value & ",
    ' " & TextBox10.Text & " ',
    #" & TextBox8.Text & "#,
    #" & TextBox9.Text & "#);"
```

Comment: what do you mean? example please :D

Comment: please take a look carefully at the code I posted, there is no space after the opening hash sign and before the closing one. how is it now, @BrianCloyLDeguzman?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is either something to do with the space between the # symbols and the dates or the "NumericUpDown1.Value" is not happy being a string without being told to do so.

It's easy to make mistakes using that kind of insert. I usually use something like the following.  (Excuse me if it's not perfect. I'm more familiar with c# and this is my attempt at translating.)

```
Dim sqlc As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand()

sqlc.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Order(Stud_ID, BookName, Quantity, sale, DateOfOrder, TimeOfOrder)  VALUES (@Stud_ID, @BookName, @Quantity, @sale, @DateOfOrder, @TimeOfOrder)

sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stud_ID", TextBox1.Text)
sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookName", ComboBox3.Text)
sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", NumericUpDown1.Value)
sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sale", TextBox10.Text)
sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfOrder", "#" & TextBox8.Text & "#")
sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeOfOrder", "#" & TextBox9.Text & "#")

try {
    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Bro_Proj.accdb"
    sqlc.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    sqlc.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.close();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    textBox1.Text = ex.ToString();
}
```